# Как вывести атрибуты всех файлов в WEB приложении

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, jsp

```
Find.java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Find {
  public  File folder = new File("");
  static String temp = "";

  private String text;

  public void setText(String text) {
                  this.text = text;
  }

  public String getText() {
                  return text;
  }

  public List<String> getList() {
                  return getFiles(new File(text));
  }

  private List<String> getFiles(File f) {
                  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

                  if (f.isDirectory()) {
                                 File[] list = f.listFiles();
                                 if (list == null) {
                                                 return result;
                                 }
                                 for (File d : f.listFiles()) {
                                                 if (d.isDirectory()) {
                                                                 result.addAll(getFiles(d));



                                                 } else {
                                                                 result.add(d.getName());
                                                                 System.out.println(d.getPath());


                                                 }
                                 }
                  }
                  return result;
  }
```

secondpage.jsp

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="ru.sbrf.asfs.stub.stubsUtils.Find"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<% Find find = new Find();
String name = request.getParameter("text");
System.out.print(name);
       find.setText(name);
       List<String> list = find.getList();

%>


<html>
<head>
<title>secondpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
       <table border="1">

                           <th value=>
                                  <c:forEach var="l" items='<%= list %>'>
                                       <c:out value="${l}"/> <br>
                                  </c:forEach>
                           </th>
                           <th Путь>

                           </th>

       </table>
       </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грешно в нашем веке скриптлеты использовать. Лучше так:

**Lister.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Lister {
    private String path;

    public Lister() {}

    public void setPath(String path) throws IOException {
        if (!new File(path).isDirectory())
            throw IOException("Not a directory!");
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() throws IOException {
        return Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
                 .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }            
}
```

**secondpage.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="lister" class="com.example.Lister">
            <jsp:setProperty property="path" value="${param.text}"/>
        </jsp:useBean>
        <table>
            <c:forEach var="f" items="${lister.files}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${f.absolutePath}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${f.length()}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${f.lastModified()}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Можно `Lister` ещё чуточку усложнить, чтобы вместо списка объектов `File` он возвращал список обёрток, красиво показывающих размер и дату модификации.

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично, работает. Только к сожалению там, где нужно стоит jdk 1.7 (Вам покажется странным, но я  это изменить не могу, так как от меня это не зависит), поэтому метод walk отсутствует.